# Events causing cross-thread error in backgroundworker_progresschanged and backgroundworker_complete

Tags: objectlistview

My VB.NET winforms app runs a timer which creates a background worker to update the objects in an ObjectListView.

In the timer loop, a number of 'device' objects are added to an observable collection (in the backgroundworker_progresschanged event) and (in the backgroundworker_complete event), I use an OLV.SetObjects(allDevices, true) to populate them.

This all works flawlessly. However, the currently selected items in the OLV are lost during the OLV.setobjects so I need to restore them.

To do this, (in the backgroundworker_complete event), I want to access the selecteditems property of the OLV but I keep getting a "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'DeviceListView1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." All attempts at trying to read the selected listviewitems (either by OLV.selecteditems or a loop reading them from the OLV) fail with the cross-thread exception.

I may misunderstand but I thought I could access GUI elements on the backgroundworker_progresschanged and backgroundworker_complete events?

Here's the relevant code:

The PopulateDevices sub is called when the timer is started and will not run again until a specific time has passed. It runs the RunWorkerAsync of the Worker.

```
    Public Sub PopulateDevices()

        ' Debug
        _UpdateCount += 1

        ' Pause the Update Timer
        UpdateTimer.Stop()

        ' Get the Starting Time of this Update
        StartTime = DateTime.Now

        ' Stop updating the DeviceListView1 ObjectListView
        ControlHelper.ControlInvoke(DeviceListView1, Sub() DeviceListView1.BeginUpdate())

        ' Clear Existing Devices from the List
        AllDevices = New TrulyObservableCollection(Of DeviceItem)

        ' Get the selected devices
        '_SelectedDevices = GetSetSelectedDevices(DeviceListView1)

        ' Prep the BackgroundWorker
        PopulateDevicesWorker = New BackgroundWorker
        PopulateDevicesWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = True

        ' Add the Event Handlers
        AddHandler PopulateDevicesWorker.DoWork, AddressOf PopulateDevicesWorkerDoWork
        AddHandler PopulateDevicesWorker.ProgressChanged, AddressOf PopulateDevicesWorkerProgressChanged
        AddHandler PopulateDevicesWorker.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf PopulateDevicesWorkerCompleted

        ' Start the BackgroundWorker
        If Not PopulateDevicesWorker.IsBusy Then
            PopulateDevicesWorker.RunWorkerAsync()
        End If

    End Sub
```

The worker will read a list of devices from a SQLite DB and (in the progresschanged event) populate an observable collection (AllDevices):

```
    Private Sub PopulateDevicesWorkerDoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs)

        ' We only continue if the \Clients\_Cache File exists and can be read
        If Not File.Exists(CacheFilePath) Then
            Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Create a new SQLite Connection & Connect to database
        Dim DBC As SQLiteDatabase = OpenDB(CacheFilePath)

        If Not IsNothing(DBC) Then

            ' Count the Rows in the \Clients\_Cache file
            Dim RowCount As Integer = CountTableRows(DBC, "_Cache")

            ' Set the SQL Query
            SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM _Cache WHERE Archived = @Archived"

            ' Create the SQLite Command
            Using SQLitecmd As SQLiteCommand = New SQLiteCommand(SqlQuery, DBC.Connection)

                SQLitecmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(String.Empty & "Archived", IIf(fMain.ButtonItem_VIEWARCHIVE.Checked, "True", "False"))

                Using SQLiteReader = SQLitecmd.ExecuteReader()

                    Dim Counter As Integer = 0

                    ' Read All Properties into the Array
                    While SQLiteReader.Read()

                        Using DeviceItem As New DeviceItem

                            With DeviceItem

' Get the Device Info here

                            End With

                            ' Report progress at regular intervals
                            PopulateDevicesWorker.ReportProgress(CInt(100 * Counter / RowCount), DeviceItem)

                            ' Increment the Counter (for Progress)
                            Counter += 1

                        End Using

                    End While

                End Using

            End Using

        End If

        CloseDB(DBC)

    End Sub
```

Here is the WorkerProgressChanged event. It adds the current device (from the worker) into the observable collection (AlLDevices)

```
    Private Sub PopulateDevicesWorkerProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)

        ' Update Status
        LabelItem_STATUS.Text = "Working.. (" & e.ProgressPercentage & "%)"

        ' Add the Device to Collection
        AllDevices.Add(TryCast(e.UserState, DeviceItem))

    End Sub
```

The WorkerCompleted event will set the objects in AllDevices to the OLV (DeviceListView1)

```
    Private Sub PopulateDevicesWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) ' Handles PopulateDevicesWorker.RunWorkerCompleted

' This is producing Cross-Thread error
        If Not IsNothing(_SelectedDevices) Then
            For Each item As ListViewItem In _SelectedDevices
                Debug.Print(item.Text)
            Next
        End If


        ' Populate the ObjectListView
        ControlHelper.ControlInvoke(DeviceListView1, Sub() DeviceListView1.SetObjects(AllDevices, True))

        ' Re-enable Form Updates
        ControlHelper.ControlInvoke(DeviceListView1, Sub() DeviceListView1.EndUpdate())

        ' If the refresh rate isn't already set, set it to the time taken to complete the Update PLUS the Seconds specified in the SETTINGS.INI File
        Dim difference As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.Subtract(StartTime)
        If UpdateTimeInSeconds = -1 Then
            UpdateTimer.Interval = (RefreshRate + difference.TotalSeconds) * 1000
        End If

        ' Restart the Update Timer
        UpdateTimer.Start()

    End Sub
```

I was under the impression, that I can update the GUI (get the OLV selecteditems, etc.) from the WorkerProgressChanged and WorkerCompleted backgroundworker events but I get the darn cross-thread error.

I'm also having to INVOKE the BEGIN\END UPDATE as calling them directly produces error.

I have read that the olv.setobjects in ObjectListView 2.91 (the version I am using) *should* persist the selections but I haven't seen this at all.

Please! What am I missing? Its probably something daft or is there another way of doing this?

Comment: What kind of Timer is UpdateTimer? If it is NOT a Forms.Timer, then it runs on a different thread. Thus, `PopulateDevices` will be called from a non GUI thread and the BackgroundWorker will run on that thread as well.

Comment: Oh for the love of ..  You're absolutely right. I was dynamically creating a system.timers.timer. I have added a windows.forms.timer and I'm no longer getting the cross-thread error. It would never have dawned on me until you explained it. Many thanks Uwe Keim.

Comment: For sake of completeness I posed an answer, so you can "close" this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using a Forms.Timer (but Timers.Timer or Threading.Timer) for your UpdateTimer, anything called from the timer "tick" event will run on a different thread.

Thus, PopulateDevices would also be called from a non GUI thread and the BackgroundWorker will run on that thread as well.